# LaTeX: multi-page table with centered cell' s content and adapted to column width

Tags: tables, longtable, overleaf, ltxtable, center

I am using Overleaf and need to create a multi-page table (longtable), composed by *n* rows and 3 columns, that has the following characteristics:

1. table width adapted to page width (column width);
2. first and second columns' cells content vertically and horizontally centered;
3. third columns' cells text wrapped.

Here is an example to better explain the format type I want to obtain:

[image]

I' ve made several attempts with these packages, but didn' t work quite well for all these characteristics:

- `\begin{longtabu} to \columnwidth {|c|c|X|}` not solving point 2 and generating a terrible row spacing;
- `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|c|c|X|}` with `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` in the preamble (to vertically center the cells' content) works just fine but won't  return a multi-page table.

What are your suggestions? Thx in advance.

Comment: you can just use a normal longtable, with three `p` (or `m`) columns. You can set the column widths so the table is full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xltabular` for a table that automaticaly adapts to the textwidth and can span multiple pages. However, please be aware that page breaks can only occur between table rows, not within them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|>{\ttfamily}l|l|X|}
\caption{a caption text} \label{key}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{DarkSeaGreen1}\thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{longer text}\\
\hline
\endhead
text & text & \lipsum[4] \\
\hline
text & text & \lipsum[4] \\
\hline
text & text & \lipsum[4] \\
\hline
text & text & \lipsum[4] \\
\hline
text & text & \lipsum[4] \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! How to add a caption? It gives me an error...

Comment: @LucaGiovanniVoglino: I ahve updated my answer to also inlcude a caption.

Comment: So appreciated, thx!